# Images not loading when relative path is used in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I was importing the images previously like this in React:

```
import person from '../images/image1.png'
```

And then using them like this:

```
<img src={person} alt="" />
```

Now I want to specify the path in the `src` itself due to some reason, like this:

```
<img src="../images/image1.png" alt="" />
```

But it's not working even though it should.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to add images in your JSX with Create React App. The first one is to use `import` as you did, to import an image that is somewhere in the `src` folder, like so:

```
import person from '../images/image1.png'
```

```
<img src={person} alt="" />
```

The second one is to give an image's path to `<img>`'s `src` attribute, but it's always relative to the `public` folder, in a way that the path should start with `/`, and `/` means `public` folder.

> See [Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) and [Using the Public Folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder) on Create React App's documentation.

For your second attempt to work, you could put the `images` folder inside the `public` folder, and get your images like so:

```
<img src="/images/image1.png" alt="" />
```

> If your React app will be in a sub folder when deployed, for the second way to work, you should add in your `package.json` this `"homepage":"www.example.com/folder"`, and use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` as below.

```
 <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/image1.png"} alt="" />
```