# React, cannot import local images inside an array to loop over

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am learning React.js and aiming to make a product page, and I have some issues with importing images from my local directory. These are from my actual project, but it's an online editor, but it should be fine because it's the same issue.
These are my files:

[image]

My App.js:

```
import "./styles.css";
import Images from "./Images";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {Images.map((content) => (
        <div className="product-image">
          <img src={content.image} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

My Images.js:

```
const Images = [
  {
    id: 1,
    image: "./img/img1.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    image: "./img/img2.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    image: "./img/img3.jpg"
  }
];

export default Images;
```

For `Image.js`, It is weird because if I make the image source to a url format, it works fine. The local directory name shouldn't be a problem because that's where I imported other sources in my project. Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Images not loading when relative path is used in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72606910/images-not-loading-when-relative-path-is-used-in-react)

Comment: It's convention to put assets like images in the public folder rather than the src folder. It may be that the online editor is making assumptions about file types.
You are also using a relative file path which is dangerous since it depends on what file you're calling it from

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you have two choices, either you put your `img` folder inside `public` folder and change `Images.js` to this:

```
const Images = [
  {
    id: 1,
    image: "/img/img1.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    image: "/img/img2.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    image: "/img/img3.jpg"
  }
];

export default Images;
```

Or you keep `img` folder inside `src` and change `Images.js` to this:

```
import img1 from "./img/img1.jpg";
import img2 from "./img/img2.jpg";
import img3 from "./img/img3.jpg";
const Images = [
  {
    id: 1,
    image: img1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    image: img2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    image: img3
  }
];

export default Images;
```

> See this Stack Overflow [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72606910/images-not-loading-when-relative-path-is-used-in-react) to know why it's like this.