# how to dynamically fetch data in react while deploying?

Tags: reactjs

Here's the thing, it all works fine if I run it with the `npm run dev` script, but images in testimonials.avatar don't render with `npm run build`.

```
const Testimonials = ({ testimonials }) => {
  return (
    <div id='testimonials' className='mt-20'>
      <div className='text-center mb-8'>
        <p className='text-xs uppercase mb-4 md:text-base'>Testimonials</p>
        <h1 className='text-3xl md:text-5xl font-bold capitalize mb-10'>Read What Other<br />have to Say</h1>
      </div>
      <div className='flex flex-col gap-4 items-center md:flex-row'>
        {testimonials.map(item =>
          <div className='bg-light-gray rounded-3xl p-8 transition-transform duration-300 hover:-translate-y-2'>
            <div className='w-32 h-32 mx-auto mb-4'>
              <img src={item.avatar} alt="Person's avatar" className='rounded-full border' />
            </div>
            <p className='font-bold text-center'>{item.fullName}</p>
            <p className='text-center mt-6'>{item.feedback}</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here I have a component which receives an array `testimonials` through props and then renders them in a div.

This is the array in `App.jsx` file.

```
const testimonials = [
    {
      avatar: '../src/images/avatars/avatar-1.png',
      fullName: 'Andrew Rathore',
      feedback: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ullamcorper scelerisque mi, in malesuada felis malesuada vel. '
    },
    {
      avatar: '../src/images/avatars/avatar-2.png',
      fullName: 'Vera Duncan',
      feedback: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ullamcorper scelerisque mi, in malesuada felis malesuada vel. '
    },
    {
      avatar: '../src/images/avatars/avatar-3.png',
      fullName: 'Mark Smith',
      feedback: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ullamcorper scelerisque mi, in malesuada felis malesuada vel. '
    }
  ];
```

I guess I know that the main reason why it does not work while deploying is because of a non-existent path since I will no longer have src/images/avatar during a deploy.

I also guess this is a dumb question because I am quite new to React and JavaScript in general, but would appreciate any answer regarding the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Images not loading when relative path is used in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72606910/images-not-loading-when-relative-path-is-used-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by creating an external file and then fetching it to the component like so.

`data.js`

```
import avatar1 from '../public/images/avatars/avatar-1.png';
import avatar2 from '../public/images/avatars/avatar-2.png';
import avatar3 from '../public/images/avatars/avatar-3.png';

export const testimonials = [
  {
    authorImg: avatar1,
    authorName: 'Andrew Rathore',
    authorText: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ullamcorper scelerisque mi, in malesuada felis malesuada vel.'
  },
  {
    authorImg: avatar2,
    authorName: 'Vera Duncan',
    authorText: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ullamcorper scelerisque mi, in malesuada felis malesuada vel.'
  },
  {
    authorImg: avatar3,
    authorName: 'Mark Smith',
    authorText: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ullamcorper scelerisque mi, in malesuada felis malesuada vel.'
  }
];
```

`Testimonials.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';

import { testimonials } from '../data/data';

const Testimonials = () => {
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col gap-4 justify-between items-center md:flex-row'>
      {testimonials.map((testimonial, index) =>
        <div key={index} className='bg-light-gray rounded-3xl p-8 transition-transform duration-300 hover:-translate-y-2'>
          <div className='w-32 h-32 mx-auto mb-4'>
            <img src={testimonial.authorImg} alt="Person's avatar" className='rounded-full border' />
          </div>
          <p className='font-bold text-center'>{testimonial.authorName}</p>
          <p className='text-center mt-6'>{testimonial.authorText}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Testimonials;
```

The main reason why it didn't work well in the first place was the fact that I specified path to the images in the object itself like so:

```
{
  key: '../../../value.png'
}
```

That is why I ran into as error every time while deploying, 'cause it simply couldn't find that path due to its non-existence.

Comment: Please improve your answer by including a code sample for what you changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the avatar path in `require()` like `require('../src/images/avatars/avatar-1.png')` I hope this works. thanks