# I cannot display images using props in React

Tags: css, reactjs, components

I am trying to dynamically add images using props in React.
I wanted to showcase the img on the grey box.
[image: img]

However I cannot seem to do so as the image is not being displayed.

I have this component that leads to another component and receives props data from data.js as shown in the image below
[image: img]

[image: img]

This is my  component
[image: img]

My CSS (Specifically the one that handles the .right classname)

[image]

This is my Folder structure

[image: img]

I have tried changing the src value directly to ./img/proj1.png but still nothing changed. I also have tried directly changing it to require, as shown below:
[image: img]
Also tried:
[image: img]
However, both just results to my website being completely blank.

May I ask what did I miss?

Comment: This may help you.  It has to do with the fact that your src directory is not the same as the one that your app is served from:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72606910/images-not-loading-when-relative-path-is-used-in-react

Comment: try adding your images to the `/public` directory and update the `src` using the new path.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set width and height for image(.imgBanner).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).