# how can I get to work my source and audio tag in React.js

Tags: html, reactjs, fetch, tags, html5-audio

That was the previous problem: I'm attempting to retrieve audio files from a folder dynamically, based on an array of data from my database. However, it only works when I import the file names manually, which is not what I intend to do. I want the program to loop through my data array and compare the file names with the strings in the array, so that I can play the corresponding audio files.

Below you can see the code already fixed. Now it is working. I had to move the audio to the public file and fix the audioPlay function

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router'
import api from '../../../Api'
import Carregando from '../../../components/Carregando'
import OffCanvas from '../../../components/OffCanvas'

const audioFilesContext = require.context(
  '../../../../public/audios/listening-reading',
  true,
  /\.mp3$/
);

const ListeningReading = () => {
  const [play, setPlay] = useState('')

  const location = useLocation()
  const conteudoAtual = {
    nivel: location.state.nivel,
    aula:  location.state.aula
  }

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() =>{
    const fetchPost = async () =>{
      setLoading(true)
      await axios.post(`${api}/listening-reading`,{
        nivel: conteudoAtual.nivel,
        aula: conteudoAtual.aula,
      }).then((response) => { 
        console.log('response')
        setPosts(response.data)
      }).catch((rejected)=> { console.error(rejected.response.data)})
      setLoading(false)
    }
    fetchPost()
  },[conteudoAtual.nivel, conteudoAtual.aula])

  const audioPlay = async () =>{
    await posts.map((post) => {
      const path = audioFilesContext.keys().find((key) => key.replace('./', '') === post.audio)
      const audioFile = path ? `../../../../public/audios/listening-reading/${path.replace('./', '')}` : null
      const audioCut = audioFile.replace('../../../../public', '')

      setPlay(audioCut)
    })
  }
  
  if(play === ''){audioPlay()}
  

  return (
    <>
      <OffCanvas/>
      <br/>
      <div className='container mt-5'>
        <h1>Listening Reading</h1>
        {
          posts.map((post) =>(
            <div key={post.id}>
              <h3>{post.titulo}</h3>
              <p className="fw-semibold">{post.texto}</p>
              <audio controls>
                <source 
                  src={play}              
                  type={"audio/mp3"}
                  />
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
              </audio>
            </div>
          ))
        }
        {loading && <Carregando/>}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default ListeningReading
```

this is how it was:
I know if I manualy import the my audio, it works, like this:
`import listenToAudio from '../../../audios/listening-reading/hello.mp3'`

if I also import using require() method it works
`const listenToAudio = require('../../../audios/listening-reading/hello.mp3')`

Now I can find the correct audio dynamicly and excute it

```
{
          posts.map((post) =>(
            <div key={post.id}>
              <h3>{post.titulo}</h3>
              <p className="fw-semibold">{post.texto}</p>
              <audio controls>
                <source 
                  src={play}              
                  type={"audio/mp3"}
                  />
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
              </audio>
            </div>
          ))
        }
```

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: yes when I initiated the project I used the command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Images not loading when relative path is used in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72606910/images-not-loading-when-relative-path-is-used-in-react)

Comment: cut my audios file and paste inside the public file and in my src I started the path with / just as the example from the link you sent and it still didn't work

Comment: Have you tried without using that `audioFilesContext`?

Comment: I got the solution!
1st I did as you suggested I move the audios to the public file.
2nd I changed the paths in my strings.
3rd I fixed the audioPlay function and got rid of the handleLoadedData function.